# Samsung galaxy 3S, battery is good, phone won't charge or power up

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, charging, power-on

I have a samsung galaxy 3S, about a week ago it rebooted itself, since then it will won't charge or turn back on, I have tested the battery to see if it was that, the battery works perfect, I have cleaned the connections to the battery and the battery itself, when i do plug it in the red charge light will come on for about 2 minutes then goes off, but still won't power up, please help, i have lots of picutures i would like to get off the phone

Answer (score 0):

If your device is not modified, the best option from here may simply be to contact Samsung and ask about using your warranty to get your device fixed. All Samsung mobile phones have a two year warranty from the moment you receive the device, so if your device is still within that period of time you should be able to, for free, have Samsung fix the device and your pictures retrieved.

Use the Samsung website for more information regarding this.

USA: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/
UK: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/